# Chart JS not working with Phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, chart.js

i got a dynamically loaded Chart working on several browsers and also on my iPhone. But when i try to open the chart with phonegap on my iPhone the canvas is totally buggy.

Are there any known issues using Chart JS with Phonegap?

it should look like this:
[image: open website via browser on iPhone]

but with Phonegap it looks like this:
[image: open Chart with Phonegap on iPhone]

HTML:

```
<div id="temp_graph" style="display:none;">
<h2 id="tmp_label"></h2>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

CSS:

```
#temp_graph {
margin-top: 5%;
width: 90%;
background-color: #fff;
display: inline-block;
padding: 2%;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 58, 0.05);
}
```

JS:

```
var temp_graph_div = document.getElementById('temp_graph');

var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    startingData = {
        labels: [tempValues[9][3], tempValues[8][3], tempValues[7][3], tempValues[6][3], tempValues[5][3], tempValues[4][3], tempValues[3][3], tempValues[2][3], tempValues[1][3], tempValues[0][3]],
        datasets: [{
              label: '°C',
              fill: false,
              lineTension: 0.1,
              backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 205, 200,0.4)",
              borderColor: "rgba(255, 205, 200,1)",
              borderCapStyle: 'butt',
              borderDash: [],
              borderDashOffset: 0.0,
              borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
              pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
              pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
              pointBorderWidth: 1,
              pointHoverRadius: 5,
              pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
              pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
              pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
              pointRadius: 1,
              pointHitRadius: 10,
              responsive: true,
              maintainAspectRatio: true,
              data: [tempValues[9][6], tempValues[8][6], tempValues[7][6], tempValues[6][6], tempValues[5][6], tempValues[4][6], tempValues[3][6], tempValues[2][6], tempValues[1][6], tempValues[0][6]]
          }]
    };

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: startingData,
});


temp_graph_div.style.display = 'inherit';
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:
added a border for the canvas and opened the website via browser (safari ios)
[image: with border and without phonegap]

added a border for the canvas and opened the website via phonegap
[image: with border and phonegap]

seems like the width is incorrect, but why are there different widths for the same mobile device?

Comment: Does it work fine when you try your code in your mobile browser (via direct link, no phonegap) ?

Comment: yep, via normal browser (safari / firefox) it works and looks like the first image above - with iPhone

Comment: Can you add a border to the chart to make sure that the window/viewport size is correctly set in phonegap?

Comment: i edited my question. See the new images :/

Comment: ... no idea? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i could fix the issue =)
The issue was caused by setting the div

```
temp_graph_div.style.display = 'inherit';
```

after creating the chart.

Now, my code looks like this (no big change, but big success):

```
        var temp_graph_div = document.getElementById('temp_graph');
    temp_graph_div.style.display = 'inherit';

    var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        startingData = {
            labels: [tempValues[9][3], tempValues[8][3], tempValues[7][3], tempValues[6][3], tempValues[5][3], tempValues[4][3], tempValues[3][3], tempValues[2][3], tempValues[1][3], tempValues[0][3]],
            datasets: [{
                  label: '°C',
                  fill: false,
                  lineTension: 0.1,
                  backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 205, 200,0.4)",
                  borderColor: "rgba(255, 205, 200,1)",
                  borderCapStyle: 'butt',
                  borderDash: [],
                  borderDashOffset: 0.0,
                  borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
                  pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                  pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                  pointBorderWidth: 1,
                  pointHoverRadius: 5,
                  pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                  pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                  pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
                  pointRadius: 1,
                  pointHitRadius: 10,
                  responsive: true,
                  maintainAspectRatio: true,
                  data: [tempValues[9][6], tempValues[8][6], tempValues[7][6], tempValues[6][6], tempValues[5][6], tempValues[4][6], tempValues[3][6], tempValues[2][6], tempValues[1][6], tempValues[0][6]]
              }]
        };


    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: startingData,
    });
```